# '403 Forbidden' apt-get update Ubuntu Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt-get

I am new to Docker, currently trying to test ping google.com within Docker container (WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker desktop).

I am trying to build an image with Ubuntu:20.04. When it comes to 'RUN apt-get update', it failed to fetch and return 'E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]'.

Also, I have built another image with Alpine:latest and 'RUN apk update' but the build was success and execute as expected. Further, 'apt-get update' works just fine inside WSL2.

These are the things that I tried (based on related problems on SO) but returns the same error:-

- change DNS within /etc/docker/daemon.json
- change the 'http' to 'ftp' to 'https' within /etc/apt/source.lists
- install apt-transport-https
- update apt mirrors accordingly to my region
- upgrade WSL2 dist to release 22.04 jammy
- remove all files within /var/lib/apt/lists/ and apt-get update
- reinstall Docker desktop

Dockerfile:

```
#pull base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#sudo su
USER root

#update and clean packages
RUN : \
    && apt-get update \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && apt-get clean \
    && :

#copy all all files in current directory into container directory /home/app
COPY . /home/app

#set /home/app as working directory
WORKDIR /home/app

#execute ping.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "ping.sh"]
```

ping.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ping google.com
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "dns": ["192.168.224.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.30.176.1
```

docker build -t test-ping-ubuntu:0.1 .

```
[+] Building 52.1s (7/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 442B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                 45.6s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                    0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:0e0402cd13f68137edb0266e1d2c682f217814420f  5.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:0e0402cd13f68137edb0266e1d2c682f217814420f  0.0s
 => => sha256:0e0402cd13f68137edb0266e1d2c682f217814420f2d43d300ed8f65479b14fb 1.42kB / 1.42kB   0.0s
 => => sha256:8eb87f3d6c9f2feee114ff0eff93ea9dfd20b294df0a0353bd6a4abf403336fe 529B / 529B       0.0s
 => => sha256:d5447fc01ae62c20beffbfa50bc51b2797f9d7ebae031b8c2245b5be8ff1c75b 1.46kB / 1.46kB   0.0s
 => => sha256:846c0b181fff0c667d9444f8378e8fcfa13116da8d308bf21673f7e4bea8d58 28.58MB / 28.58MB  4.0s
 => => extracting sha256:846c0b181fff0c667d9444f8378e8fcfa13116da8d308bf21673f7e4bea8d580        0.9s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 500B                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [2/4] RUN :     && apt-get update     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*     && apt-get clean  1.3s
------
 > [2/4] RUN :     && apt-get update     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*     && apt-get clean     && ::
#6 0.405 Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
#6 0.405   403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#6 0.623 Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
#6 0.623   403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.631 Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
#6 0.631   403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.639 Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
#6 0.639   403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.642 Reading package lists...
#6 0.648 E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
#6 0.648 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#6 0.648 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
#6 0.648 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.648 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.648 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
#6 0.648 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#6 0.648 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c :     && apt-get update     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*     && apt-get clean     && :]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You should speak with your network admin. But as you said that alpine is working with update, network generally seems to not be blocked.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I changed from Docker-Desktop to Docker-CE and it works.

Comment: @JHBonarius If you want to stay on docker desktop you can also try to switch to an alpine image as base and use "RUN apk add" to install whatever you need instead of apt-get. This has in my experience no bug.

Comment: @MircoS. Not possible I think, as we're not in control of the underlying dependency of the container we are referencing. And we don't want to maintain it, as we rely on their expertise

Answer (score 1):

Can you add:

```
apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
```

before `apt-update` command

Comment: hi @vagitus thank you for your attention. I've tried this, still it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing your error message it seems to me to be an issue with the docker cache.

Look after the error, you see that there is a probleme with the signature executing apt update.

You said you installed Docker-desktop. Have you removed everything before? Reset to factory settings? Clean all?

```
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

should delete also all

Your alpine image is executed well, because it does not update anything from the ubuntu repository which is generating the issue. (as alpine is a different linux distro)

You dont need to edit dns settings or anything else.

I tested your image, it is working fine.

Think, when you build the docker image it is not using your local wsl distro. It uses the Ubuntu version in the image itselfs, which comes from

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

To check if it is related to the docker cache you can also try

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
```

Another thing you can also add a .dockerignore file.

And inside put the folders where docker should ignore the cache when building the image. Find more info here:

```
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/what-is-a-dockerignore-file-and-why-you-should-be-using-them/
```

Please let me know if this could resolve your issue.

Update:

Executed with gitbash

```
 docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
b206807c674c
e63668bd62ed
276f59d1c41c
8b4c3d66dd0e
1bce2f46e207
f53fb77ce6f0
9193b1727cf9
c6f93789d038
```

If you run them in WSL, Think:

WSL is a virtual macchine.

execute docker ps -aq from there, if it doesnt return anything you dont have containers in WSL running. So the $(docker ps -aq) in docker rm $(docker ps -aq) is empty and the error atleast one argument ist required comes from there.

Update Docker-Desktop, there was a bug reletad to images in the version before.

Comment: Hi @Ralle, I did reset to factory settings, remove all files related to docker and reinstall twice, but errors remain the same. I will try the .dockerignore file and update it here later. I really appreciate your attention. Btw, is this somehow related to the network domain restriction in my company? I did on my personal network with the exact code (copy and paste) and it works just fine.

Comment: Speak with your network admin.

Comment: If I run your `docker rm ...` command, it says "_"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument._". Both in powershell and ubuntu WSL. Same for the `rmi`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Try it with the gitbash.